# How to populate a linked list with strings using new lines as delimiters?

Tags: c, string, linked-list

I have the following linked list struct:

```
struct _node {
    char *string;
    struct _node *next;
}

struct _list {
    struct _node *head;
    struct _node *tail;
}
```

I want to write a function that takes in a string as input and uses newline characters as delimiters to populate the linked list with strings.

For example, if the input string was "First\nSecond\nThird\n", then the function
    struct _list *newList(char text[]);

should return the following linked list:

```
[First]->[Second]->[Third]->NULL // this is correct
```

The function I wrote doesn't work properly because the linked list I get looks like this:

```
[First]->[Second]->[Third]->[]->NULL // this is wrong
```

Here is my function:

```
struct _list * newList(char text[]) {
    int letterCount = 1;
    int flag = 0;
    int step = 0;
    char currChar;

    struct _list * newList = malloc(sizeof(struct _list));

    assert(newList != NULL);

    newList->head = NULL;
    newList->last = NULL;
    newList->size = 0;

    while(flag != 1) {
        currChar = text[letterCount];
        if (currChar == '\n') {
            struct _node * newNode = createNode(strlcpy(text,step,letterCount));

            if(newList->head == NULL) {
                newList->head = newNode;
            }
            else{
                newList->last->next = newNode;
            }

            newList->last = newNode;
            step += (letterCount-step) + 1;
        }
        else if (currChar == '\0') {
            struct _node * newNode = createNode(strlcpy(text,step,letterCount));

            if(newList->head == NULL) {
                newList->head = newNode;
            }
            else {
                newList->last->next = newNode;
            }

            newList->last = newNode;
            flag = 1;
        }

        letterCount++;
    }

    return newList;
}
```

Another approach is using tokens:

```
struct _list * newList(char text[]){
        struct _list * newList = NULL;
        newList = malloc(sizeof(struct _list));
        assert(newList != NULL);
        newList->head = NULL;
        newList->tail = NULL;

        char *token = strtok(text, "\n");
        while (token != NULL){
                struct _node * newNode = createNode(token);
                appendList(newList, newNode);
                token = strtok(NULL, "\n");
        }
        return newList;
}
```

However, I get a `bus error 10` when I use the second method.

Comment: Besides your problem you seem to be using strlcpy wrong. In my manual it takes a `char*` as second argument while you provide an `int`. Furthermore I am not sure if it is allowed to call it with possibly overlapping buffers.

Comment: I wrote my own strCpy function. Is there a build in function that achieves what I am trying to do? Has a step parameter and a number of characters to copy?

Comment: If that is your function then you should not name it like an existing [function](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=strlcpy&sektion=3).
And you should not name any function str* as this is reserved for standard library functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create a new node whenever you find `\n` or `\0`.
In your case your text ends immediately after the last `\n` and hence you create a node with 0 chacters.

Before calling `createNode()` you should simply check if you collected any characters since the last node was created.

Otherwise you will also get empty nodes if you have two `\n` without text in between.

The check could look like this:

```
else if (currChar == '\0') {
  if (letterCount >= step+1)
  {
    struct _node * newNode = createNode(strlcpy(text,step,letterCount));

    if(newList->head == NULL) {
      newList->head = newNode;
    }
    else {
      newList->last->next = newNode;
    }
    newList->last = newNode;
  }
  flag = 1;
}
```

Regarding your second approach:
How do you provide the text for your test? If it is a string literal, you cannot modify it and `strtok()` will fail. Apart from that I think `strtok()` is more suitable for your problem.

Comment: I want to create an empty node when I have `"\n\n"` but I don't want an empty node at the end when I have something like `"Last\n\0"`. Also, the input has to be char text[] so this means strtok is out of the question?

Comment: OK, then you only need to add the check at the end of the file. You can use `strtok` but you need to make sure that the text is not a string literal. How do you call your function?

Comment: `struct _list *newTextList = newList("First\nSecond\n");`

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the check? Do I do it in `else if (currChar == '\0')`

Comment: @user6005857 this is exactly such a string literal that you are not allowed to use. Use something like this:
`char text[] = "First\nSecond\n"; newList(text);` This will make a copy of the literal into memory that may be written to.